# Python regex look-behind strange behaviour with character '^'

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

In Python's regex: why does `regex1` complain about fixed-width look-behinds if `regex2` does not? Is `^` (start marker) more than 1 character?

Regex1

```
(?<=^|b)[0-9]
```

Regex2

```
(?<=a|b)[0-9]
```

Reproduceable in https://regex101.com/r/L5J47R/2

Comment: `^` is zero width match and Python regex engine doesn't support alternation of zero with and non-zero alternations in lookbehind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reason why first regex is nor working in Python because `^` is a zero width match and Python regex engine doesn't support alternation of zero with and non-zero alternations in the lookbehind assertion.

This is however supported in other engines such as Java, PHP, Perl, C# etc.

To solve this problem, you can use this regex:

```
(?:^|(?<=b))[0-9]
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/L5J47R/3)